# Redirect POST Data by htaccess in Phalcon

Tags: php, .htaccess, phalcon

I have following .htaccess RewriteRule:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteRule  ^$ public/    [L]
    RewriteRule  (.*) public/$1 [L]

    RewriteRule upload.php upload [NC,L]

</IfModule>
```

However when I try to send post throught /upload.php it redirect me to my login page instead of sending data by /upload.

Could you tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I've done different way by adding custom routing:

```
$router->add('/upload\.php', array(
    'controller' => 'upload',
    'action' => 'index',
));
```